# Angular 8 both child routes pointing to same component

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have parent root like following

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'parent',
    component: ParentComponent,
    children: CHILD_TAB_ROUTES,
  },
]


Than i have child tabs as following

export const CHILD_TAB_ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'childA', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'childA',
    component: ModelAComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'childB',
    component: ModelBComponent,
  },
  { path: 'childC', component: ModelCComponent },
];
```

So 3 routes like following and when the user clicks on parent by default he is rendered childA

```
parent/childA
parent/childB
parent/childC
```

Now i want to have a route like following which i want to have the same component ModelAComponent

```
parent/childA/:id
```

How to make `parent/childA/:id` go to `ModelAComponent` considering it has a different route ?

Comment: Well, add a route for that path, with that component. It's just another route. What's the concrete problem?

Comment: Do you want the route `parent/childA/:id` to show in the main router outlet? Otherwise just add a path as @JBNizet says

Answer (score 0):

You add it as another route for the children at the same level.

```
export const CHILD_TAB_ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'childA', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'childA/:id',
    component: ModelAComponent,
  }, {
    path: 'childA',
    component: ModelAComponent,
  },
  ....
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the route `'childA/:id'` below `'childA'`.

```
export const CHILD_TAB_ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'childA', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'childA',
    component: ModelAComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'childA/:id',
    component: ModelAComponent,

  },
  {
    path: 'childB',
    component: ModelBComponent,
  },
  { path: 'childC', component: ModelCComponent },
];
```

In your `modelA.component.ts`, use `ActivatedRoute` service to get the param.
Code like:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

export class ModelAComponent implements OnInit  {
   contructor(
      private route: ActivatedRoute
   ) {}

   ngOnInit() {
     const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('userid');

     if (id) {
        console.log(`route = 'parent/childA/:id'`);
     } else {
        console.log(`route = 'parent/childA'`);
     }

   }
}
```

See detail in the [angular router document](https://angular.io/guide/router).